# Changing a component dynamically in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a viewport containing 2 components a list on a left and a central window , I want to display different component in the central window dependent on what user selected in the list on the left side, I tried to accomplish this by dynamically removing and adding components but it was only a partial success , I was able to remove component but not to add it back, bellow you can see a sample of an approach I used.

```
Ext.define('LabSite.view.Viewport', {
    id: "MainViewPort",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires:[
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Ext.layout.container.Border',
        'LabSite.view.Location'
    ],

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    items: [{
        region: 'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'PC lab managment',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'dataview',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('areaStores'),          
            cls: 'feed-list',
            itemSelector: '.feed-list-item',
            overItemCls: 'feed-list-item-hover',
            tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="feed-list-item">{name}</div></tpl>',
            listeners: {
                selectionchange: function(selmodel, selection) {
                    var xtype=selection[0].data.name.toLowerCase();

                    var centr=Ext.getCmp('centerView');
                    var viewPort=Ext.getCmp('MainViewPort');
                    viewPort.remove(centr);
                    var newcmp=new Ext.Component ({ region: 'center',
                                   id:'centerView',
                                   xtype:'locations'});                                

                    viewPort.add(newcmp);
                    viewPort.doLayout( );

                }           
            }           
        }]
    },
    { region: 'center',
      id:'centerView',
      xtype:'locations'}
    ]   
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExtJS does not allow for the removal/insertion of a `center` component from a border layout. You could try making your 'centerView' component a container/panel with `layout: fit`, and then add or remove components to and from it as needed.

Comment: It does if you're not using the MVC syntax, by using `getCmp()` and then doing `remove()` and `add()` on that object.

Answer (score 9):

What M.K. posted is the best way to do it, however I had a side point. When you're updating a layout dynamically, Ext will automatically re-layout for you, so the doLayout call is redundant and adding extra overhead. Secondly, it's also inefficient because the remove, then the add will trigger a layout. Assuming you're using >= 4.1, you should do something like this:

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();
center.remove(0);
center.add({
    xtype: 'newcmp'
});
Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```